# Non-square linear transformation on an embedded manifold.

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

I have a $k$-dimensional topological manifold $M$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($k<n$). And a linear transformation given by $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Assuming that $m>n$, I want to prove that the resulting manifold:  ($Tx$  $\forall x \in M$) it still $k$-dimensional.

For $n=m$ it is obvious because the transformation is a homeomorfism (if the transformation matrix is non-singular). But the problem to me is the fact that the linear transformation is non-square.

Edit:
Assume dim Im $T$ = n

Comment: Take T=0, then $\{Tx:\ x\in M\}=0$ is not $k$-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I should have been more specific on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: By a linear change of coordinates you can reduce yourself to the case 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &\ldots & 0 \\ 
\ldots  & \ldots &\ldots  \\
0& \ldots & 1 \\ 
0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
 0 & \ldots & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$